# combobox won't expand in Ext.Dialog

Tags: extjs, combobox, modal-dialog, z-index

I wanted to show Ext.Dialog (window2) from another Dialog (window1) and the only way to successfully do it was to add

```
    initialize: function() {
        var me = this;
        this.setZIndex(1500000);
        me.callParent();
    },
```

in the initialization event of window2. But the problem is that combobox in window2 doesn't work properly. It is shown, but it won't expand (or at least the list is not shown). If I omit setting the zindex of window2, that combobox works properly, but the window2 is shown below the window1 (so, everything is ok with combobox store, but the problem is somewhere else).

The question is: how to show dialog that contains combobox over another dialog?

I even tried to put

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    zindex: 2500000,
}
```

and

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    listeners: {
       initialize: function() {
            this.setZIndex(2500000);
       }
    }
}
```

for combobox component itself, but it didn't make any effect.

Comment: May you provide some fiddle sample?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't.

Comment: as Arthur says. Use: `fiddle.sencha.com` to help us help you.